# standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" building docker image

Tags: git, docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to generate a docker image based on a binary of Go. I have the next Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /

# Now just add the binary
RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
ADD mybinary /
ADD config /config
ADD data /data

ENTRYPOINT ["./mybinary"]
```

And I built the binary by doing:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o mybinary
```

The binary works pretty good if I executed alone, and the docker image is created as well, but in the moment of execution then I get the error:

```
 standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I read in many post that it's something regarding git, so, I deleted and cloned the project again but still I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your docker image starts from alpine linux dstro. Hence you should use a supported cpu architecture

`GOARCH=amd64` instead of `GOARCH=386`.

You can see other supported architectures here. https://hub.docker.com/r/library/alpine/

Links to the alpine docker images of other architectures  can be found 
here https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64